# WooCommerce minimum order fee for products in specific category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I want to add a fee in my woocommerce store for orders under a specific amount (value, not quantity).

I am using *"[WooCommerce dynamic minimum order amount based fee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45761434/woocommerce-dynamic-minimum-order-amount-based-fee/45765250#45765250)"* answer code that works perfectly.

Now I am trying to change this functionand to apply it only to items from a specific product category. Basically, I have to sum the value of all the products in cart that matches the specific category and use this value for fee calculation.

How can I reach this goal?

Answer (score 1):

The following revisited code will handle specific defined product categories. You will have to define:

- Your specific product categories in the 1st function.
- The minimal order amount in the 2nd and 3rd functions.

The code:

```
// Get the cart items subtotal amount from specific product categories
function get_specific_cart_items_total( $cart ) {
    $categories   = array('t-shirts'); // <=== Define your product categories
    $items_amount = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $items_amount += $item['line_subtotal'];
        }
    }
    return $items_amount;
}

// Add a custom fee (displaying a notice in cart page)
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_surcharge', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_surcharge( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $min_price     = 200; // The minimal cart amount

    $current_price = get_specific_cart_items_total( $cart );
    $custom_fee    = $min_price - $current_price;

    if ( $custom_fee > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( __('Minimum Order Adjustment'), $custom_fee, true );

        // NOTICE ONLY IN CART PAGE
        if( is_cart() ){
            wc_print_notice( get_custom_fee_message( $min_price, $current_price ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}

// Displaying the notice on checkout page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'custom_surcharge_message', 10 );
function custom_surcharge_message(  ) {
    $min_price     = 200; // The minimal cart amount

    $cart          = WC()->cart;
    $current_price = get_specific_cart_items_total( $cart );
    $custom_fee    = $min_price - $current_price;

    // NOTICE ONLY IN CHECKOUT PAGE
    if ( $custom_fee > 0 ) {
        wc_print_notice( get_custom_fee_message( $min_price, $current_price ), 'error' );
    }
}

// The fee notice message
function get_custom_fee_message( $min_price, $current_price ) {
    return sprintf(
        __('We have a minimum %s per order from specific categories. As your current order is only %s, an additional fee will be applied.', 'woocommerce'),
        wc_price( $min_price ),
        wc_price( $current_price )
    );
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

---

**Option:** To handle **parent product categories** too, add the following additional function:

```
// Custom conditional function that handle parent product categories too
function has_product_categories( $categories, $product_id = 0 ) {
    $parent_term_ids = $categories_ids = array(); // Initializing
    $taxonomy        = 'product_cat';
    $product_id      = $product_id == 0 ? get_the_id() : $product_id;

    if( is_string( $categories ) ) {
        $categories = (array) $categories; // Convert string to array
    }

    // Convert categories term names and slugs to categories term ids
    foreach ( $categories as $category ){
        $result = (array) term_exists( $category, $taxonomy );
        if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
            $categories_ids[] = reset($result);
        }
    }

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // It is the Main category term and we set it.
        }
    }
    return array_intersect( $categories_ids, array_unique($parent_term_ids) ) ? true : false;
}
```

And replace in the first function this line:

```
if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
```

by this:

```
if( has_product_categories( $categories, $item['product_id'] ) ) {
```

Comment: Hello, I tested the code above but I noticed some problems with products in cart. Basically, the extra fee is applied with items from different categories too, expecially when I add/remove products. It seems that the  $custom_fee variable don't update when the cart is updated.

Comment: @MarcoBocola Sorry but I have tested again my code and works perfectly… For your categories problem I have made an update (check)… Now for the refresh problem, in your case there is something else that is making trouble. It can be your other customizations,  your theme customizations or a plugin (this code is tested and works on last WooCommerce version with storefront theme).